# I'm learning RoR through lynda.com and i need help solving this issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the error i'm getting

NoMethodError in Subjects#edit

Showing /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code/app/views/subjects/edit.html.erb    where line #7 raised:
 undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
 Extracted source (around line #7):

```
     <h2>Update Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @subjects.id}) do |f| %>

   <table summary="Subject form fields">
       <tr>
```

Rails.root: /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/subjects/edit.html.erb:7:in        `_app_views_subjects_edit_html_erb__3163959245167106416_44757760'

```
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"6"}
```

This is My Subject Controller

```
    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    list
    render('list')
  end   

  def list 
    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
  end

  def show
     @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
     @subject = Subject.new(:Name => "")
  end

  def create
  #new_position = params[:subject].delete(:position)
  # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
  @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
  # Save the object
 if @subject.save
  @subject.move_to_position(new_position)
  # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
  flash[:notice] = "Subject Created."
  redirect_to(:action => 'list')
  else
  # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
  @subject_count = Subject.count +1
  render('new')
  end  
end 

  private

  def subject_params 
  allow = [:name, :position, :visible, :created_at, :updated_at]
  params.require(:subject).permit(allow)
  end

  def edit 
   @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  # find a new object using form parameters
  @subject = Subject.find.(params[:id])
  # Save the object
  if @subject.update_attributes(params[:subject])
  # If save update, redirect to the list action
  redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @subject.id)
  else
  # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
  render('edit')
  end  
end 

  def edit 
   @subject = Subject.find.(params[:id])
  end    
end
```

this is my edit.html.erb file

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

 <div class="subject edit">
   <h2>Update Subject</h2>

<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>

   <table summary="Subject form fields">
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <td><%= f.text_field(:Name) %></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Position</th>
         <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>Visible</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
       </tr>
      </table>

  <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("Update Subject") %>
   </div>

  <% end %>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'edit' method is defined as private.  Move it above the private modifier.

Also remove the id from the url dictionary and add it as a hidden value in the form body.

```
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
<table summary="Subject form fields">
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:Name) %></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Position</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= submit_tag("Update Subject") %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: NoMethodError in Subjects#edit

Showing /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code/app/views/subjects/edit.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #7):

5
6
7
8
9
10
              

 

  <h2>Update Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @subjects.id}) do |f| %>

   <table summary="Subject form fields">
       <tr>

Rails.root: /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code

Comment: <h2>Update Subject</h2>

        <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id =>    @subjects.id}) do |f| %>

       <table summary="Subject form fields">
           <tr>

Comment: You should add the id as a hidden field in the form and remove the :id=>@subjects.id from the :url=>{} dictionary.

Comment: /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code/app/views/subjects/edit.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}' ..., :url => {:action => 'update') do |f| @output_buffer.safe_a... ... ^ /home/ktutor/Documents/simple_code/app/views/subjects/edit.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: <h2>Update Subject</h2>

 <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update') do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
<table summary="Subject form fields">
   <tr>

Comment: this is what im getting now                                                  thank you for helping me

Comment: There was a typo in my code.  at url => {}.  Try now.

Comment: great! no problem!  Please accept the answer if it was suffcient